# Troubleshooting WLAN connectivity and SSH freeze

Tags: networking, wireless, ssh

On WLAN, SSH sessions to remote hosts suddenly hang/freeze for like 1 to 2 minutes and continue afterwards (no restart of ssh necessary, they just hang and catch up later). I usually have long running SSH sessions and this happens in the same session like two to three times per hour. If a ping to the remote host is running in the background it reports 0% packet loss.

When working over cable Ethernet, no freezes happen at all. So I guess this an issue with the WLAN connectivity. I already tried:

- getting closer to the access point
- tried with the Tethering on my Smartphone instead of an access point
- tried 2.4ghz and 5ghz WLAN
- disabled power management / power saving on my Laptop
- disabled ufw
- disabled keep-alive in ssh_config

It's always the same: SSH freezes, but no packet loss reported by ping. All the other applications (e.g. mail client with an open IMAP session) are not impacted.

I'm a bit clueless on how to further debug that, any hints are appreciated.

Using a "Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 9560" controller on Ubuntu 19.04, configured by NetworkManager, all packets up to date and linux-image-generic 5.0.0.21.22.